# how to print escape character in string taken from command line argument?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

After compiling the following code, I runs it like

input: `./a.out stack'\n'overflow`

output:

```
stack\noverflow
```

input: `./a.out stack"\n"overflow`

output:

```
stack\noverflow
```

input: `./a.out stack\\noverflow`

output:

```
stack\noverflow
```

expected output for above inputs:

```
stack    
overflow
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("string from comand line : %s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: You need to do this on your own by processing `argv[1]` yourself. What is your platform?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 , 64bit , gcc compiler .

Comment: you could just : `./a.out "stack<PRESS ENTER HERE>overflow"`, and there will be an actual newline in the string, rather than an escaped character.

Comment: I need to invoke through socket programming by using function " system " , there is no user is there to hit the enter key . And why down vote dear I didn't asked anything wrong .

Comment: @vishwaraj : I didn't downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this program , input : stack'\n'overflow
output : stack
overflow

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<string.h>  

void addescapeseq(char *ptr)  
{  
    char *temp;  
    while(strstr(ptr,"\\n")||strstr(ptr,"\\t")||strstr(ptr,"\\r"))  
    {  
        if(temp=strstr(ptr,"\\n"))  
        {  
            *temp=10;  
            strcpy(temp+1,temp+2);  
        }  
        else if(temp=strstr(ptr,"\\r"))  
        {  
            *temp=13;  
            strcpy(temp+1,temp+2);  
        }
        else if(temp=strstr(ptr,"\\t"))  
        {  
            *temp=9;  
            strcpy(temp+1,temp+2);  
        }  
    }  
}  

int main(int argc,char *argv[])  
{  
    addescapeseq(argv[1]);  
    printf("Data : %s\n",argv[1]);  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

"Escape sequences" in string or characters in code is resolved by the compiler at *compile-time*. It's not handled at run-time at all.

If you're in a POSIX system (like macOS or Linux or similar) then you can use the shell to insert the newlines for you when running your program:

```
$ ./a.out '`echo -n -e "stack\noverflow"`'
```

That will invoke the `echo` command and ask it to echo the string `"stack\noverflow"` without trailing newline (that's what the `-n` options does). The embedded `"\n"` will be parsed by `echo` (because of the `-e` option) and insert a newline into the string it "prints". The output printed by `echo` will be passed as a single argument to your program.

The only other option is to explicitly parse the string in your program, and print a newline when it finds the character `'\\'` followed by the character `'n'`.

Answer (score 1):

try to work with this function :

```
void ft_putstr(char *s)
{
  int i = 0;

  while (s[i])
    {
      if (s[i] == '\\')
        {
          if (s[i + 1] == 'n')
            {
              putchar('\n');
              i += 2;
            }
        }
      if (s[i] != '\0')
        {
          putchar(s[i]);
          i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will only print the escape character , but I need to modify the main string which can be use in further program.

Comment: use this function instead of printf, it prints the hole string, like this ft_putstr(av[1]), i think it works i test it